# IIS gives me a 404 error on the root of my website. I have a similarly configured website which works just fine on another port

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have two versions of the same ASP.NET MVC web app configured in IIS, each with somewhat different code (one is a fork of the other). The original one on port 31503 works just fine, but I just added a fork of it on port 44444, and I get a 404 error:

> Server Error in '/' Application
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3429.0

when I run that app. I checked to make sure that they are pointing to analogous folders in their respective folder structures. I'm not sure what could be wrong with the configuration of the forked app; what would be a good place to look to see what might be different?

I also tried running the fork in the Visual Studio debugger, but that doesn't work because it's configured somewhere to use port 31503, which is already in use by the original app. I replaced all instances of 31503 with 44444 in the forked code, but it still tries to run on port 31503 when I debug it, so I don't know what's going on there either!

edit: if I disable the port 31503 app and try to debug the fork, I get this error:

[image]

Not sure where the port 56115 came from...

Comment: how does the web.config look like??

Comment: It has a lot of sensitive data in it that I'd rather not share ;) Is there something in particular that might be causing a problem?

Comment: I did compare the two web.configs in WinMerge and they are identical, however.

Comment: I was just thinking about if there is any path parameters that can be interfering. I would try creating another site and point it to the same directory and see if that works. not a fix, but a suggestion

Comment: @Majid thanks for trying to clean up my post, but code tags are for code, not technical terms; I reverted your edit. Just thought I'd bring this to your attention so you can be a better editor! :)

Comment: It is rather strange to see "Failed to launch debug adapter" there. Are you doing remote debugging?

Comment: @ekolis thank you :)